# Como retornar o último ID de uma consulta

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou trabalhando com um banco Oracle

Tenho duas tabelas:

**Tabela Aluno:**

```
IDALUNO
IDMATRICULA
FASE
```

**Tabela Teste:**

```
IDTESTE
IDALUNO
IDMATRICULA
TESTE
STATUS
```

Possuo ainda uma view que me dá as informações dos alunos

**View Consulta Alunos**

```
IDALUNO
IDMATRICULA
NOME_ALUNO
ESCOLA
```

Em resumo, cada **Aluno** pode possuir mais de um **Teste**, e eu tenho que construir um `SELECT` que me retorne um **Teste** de cada **Aluno**, se houver mais de um **Teste**, irei retornar somente o último **Teste** inserido no sistema.

Existe a função `MAX` so que não sei ao certo como se aplicaria nessa minha função... 
Minha `query` está assim:

```
SELECT IDTESTE, IDALUNO, IDMATRICULA, CA.NOME_ALUNO, CA.ESCOLA FROM ALUNO MA 
INNER JOIN VW_CONSULTA_ALUNOS CA ON CA.IDALUNO = MA.IDALUNO
INNER JOIN TESTE MT ON MT.IDALUNO = MA.IDALUNO AND MT.IDMATRICULA = MA.IDMATRICULA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que o último teste é o de maior ID, a função MAX vai numa subquery para retornar este maior ID. A subquery, por sua vez, é filtrada pelo aluno retornado pela query principal.

```
SELECT IDTESTE, IDALUNO, IDMATRICULA, CA.NOME_ALUNO, CA.ESCOLA FROM ALUNO MA 
INNER JOIN VW_CONSULTA_ALUNOS CA ON CA.IDALUNO = MA.IDALUNO
INNER JOIN TESTE MT ON MT.IDALUNO = MA.IDALUNO AND MT.IDMATRICULA = MA.IDMATRICULA
WHERE IDTESTE = (SELECT MAX(IDTESTE) FROM TESTE WHERE IDALUNO = MA.IDALUNO)
```

Comment: consigo fazer isso dentro de uma subquery a partir de um inner join?

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Não entendi a pergunta. A query funcionou? Você quer que ela fique diferente?

Comment: Deu certinho @Caffé, eu tinha tentado fazer de uma outra forma, so que ai envolveria `group by` e acabaria saindo uma gambiarra, desse seu jeito foi bem mais eficiente

Answer (score 1):

Não testei no ORACLE mas no MySQL funciona.

```
SELECT MAX(IDALUNO), IDMATRICULA, CA.NOME_ALUNO, CA.ESCOLA FROM ALUNO MA 
INNER JOIN VW_CONSULTA_ALUNOS CA ON CA.IDALUNO = MA.IDALUNO
INNER JOIN TESTE MT ON MT.IDALUNO = MA.IDALUNO AND MT.IDMATRICULA = MA.IDMATRICULA
GROUP BY CA.NOME_ALUNO
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
SELECT MAX(idteste) ultimo_teste
      ,idaluno
      ,idmatricula
      ,ca.nome_aluno
      ,ca.escola
  FROM aluno ma
 INNER JOIN vw_consulta_alunos ca
    ON ca.idaluno = ma.idaluno
 INNER JOIN teste mt
    ON mt.idaluno = ma.idaluno
   AND mt.idmatricula = ma.idmatricula
 GROUP BY idaluno
         ,idmatricula
         ,ca.nome_aluno
         ,ca.escola;
```

No caso utilizei a função analítica `MAX`, com a cláusula `GROUP BY`.
No caso, ele não retorna o último teste, ele retorna o maior teste para cada aluno.
Mas pela tua explicação como o teste é uma sequência, então pegando o `MAX` já funciona.